# Cypher query - only one direction result

Tags: cypher

I have the graph at the bottom.
I want to bring all the connections between `GraphTarget` that the `FriendOf` is **not** b-directional.
Everything inside the red zone, (max 5 levels of `FriendOf`)

http://console.neo4j.org/r/pb9mp - a place to play with the query

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help you a bit:

```
MATCH (gt:GraphTarget)
MATCH path_account = (:Account)-[:FriendOf*]->(:Account)
MATCH (account1:Account)-[:FriendOf]->(account2:Account)
MATCH (account2:Account)-[:FriendOf]->(account1:Account)
WHERE none(node IN nodes(path_account) WHERE node=account1 OR node=account2)
RETURN gt, nodes(path_account)
```

I checked it graphically in Neo4j and this is the result:

Your graph
[image: Your graph]

The query
[image: Your query]